# Procedural macro to derive de/serialization trait from/to little endian bytes

Tags: rust, macros

I wrote a trait library that allows the de-/serialization of data structures from/to little endian bytes [1](https://github.com/PaulmannLighting/le-stream).

For it I now wrote my first procedural macro [2](https://github.com/PaulmannLighting/le-stream-derive) to be able to derive the traits `FromLeBytes` and `ToLeBytes` for `struct`s:

```rust
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, parse_quote, Data, DeriveInput, Fields, GenericParam, Generics};

pub fn from_le_bytes(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    // Parse the input tokens into a syntax tree.
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);

    // Used in the quasi-quotation below as `#name`.
    let name = input.ident;

    let generics = add_trait_bounds(input.generics);
    let (impl_generics, ty_generics, where_clause) = generics.split_for_impl();

    // Generate an expression to sum up the heap size of each field.
    let body = impl_body(&input.data);

    let expanded = quote! {
        // The generated impl.
        impl #impl_generics le_stream::FromLeBytes for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {
            fn from_le_bytes<T>(bytes: &mut T) -> le_stream::Result<Self>
            where
                T: Iterator<Item = u8>
            {
                #body
            }
        }
    };

    // Hand the output tokens back to the compiler.
    proc_macro::TokenStream::from(expanded)
}

// Add a bound `T: FromLeBytes` to every type parameter T.
fn add_trait_bounds(mut generics: Generics) -> Generics {
    for param in &mut generics.params {
        if let GenericParam::Type(ref mut type_param) = *param {
            type_param.bounds.push(parse_quote!(le_stream::FromLeBytes));
        }
    }
    generics
}

fn impl_body(data: &Data) -> TokenStream {
    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref structure) => match structure.fields {
            Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                let mut tokens = TokenStream::new();
                let mut constructor_fields = TokenStream::new();

                for field in &fields.named {
                    let item_name = field.ident.clone().expect("struct field has no name");
                    let item_type = &field.ty;

                    tokens.extend(quote! {
                            let #item_name = <#item_type as le_stream::FromLeBytes>::from_le_bytes(bytes)?;
                        });

                    constructor_fields.extend(quote! {
                        #item_name,
                    });
                }

                tokens.extend(quote! { Ok(Self { #constructor_fields }) });
                tokens
            }
            _ => unimplemented!(),
        },
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

```rust
use proc_macro2::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, parse_quote, Data, DeriveInput, Fields, GenericParam, Generics};

pub fn to_le_bytes(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    // Parse the input tokens into a syntax tree.
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);

    // Used in the quasi-quotation below as `#name`.
    let name = input.ident;

    let generics = add_trait_bounds(input.generics);
    let (impl_generics, ty_generics, where_clause) = generics.split_for_impl();

    // Generate an expression to sum up the heap size of each field.
    let (iterator_statement, iterator_type) = impl_body(&input.data);

    let expanded = quote! {
        // The generated impl.
        impl #impl_generics le_stream::ToLeBytes for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {
            type Iter = #iterator_type;

            fn to_le_bytes(&self) -> <Self as ToLeBytes>::Iter {
                #iterator_statement
            }
        }
    };

    // Hand the output tokens back to the compiler.
    proc_macro::TokenStream::from(expanded)
}

// Add a bound `T: ToLeBytes` to every type parameter T.
fn add_trait_bounds(mut generics: Generics) -> Generics {
    for param in &mut generics.params {
        if let GenericParam::Type(ref mut type_param) = *param {
            type_param.bounds.push(parse_quote!(le_stream::ToLeBytes));
        }
    }
    generics
}

fn impl_body(data: &Data) -> (TokenStream, TokenStream) {
    match *data {
        Data::Struct(ref structure) => match structure.fields {
            Fields::Named(ref fields) => {
                let mut iterator_type = quote! { std::iter::Empty<u8> };
                let mut iterator_statement = quote! { std::iter::empty::<u8>() };

                for field in &fields.named {
                    let item_name = field.ident.clone().expect("struct field has no name");
                    let item_type = &field.ty;

                    iterator_statement.extend(quote! {
                        .chain(<#item_type as le_stream::ToLeBytes>::to_le_bytes(&self.#item_name))
                    });

                    iterator_type = quote! {
                        std::iter::Chain<#iterator_type, <#item_type as le_stream::ToLeBytes>::Iter>
                    };
                }

                (iterator_statement, iterator_type)
            }
            _ => unimplemented!(),
        },
        Data::Enum(_) | Data::Union(_) => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

```rust
mod from_le_bytes;
mod to_le_bytes;

use from_le_bytes::from_le_bytes;
use to_le_bytes::to_le_bytes;

#[proc_macro_derive(FromLeBytes)]
pub fn derive_from_le_bytes(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    from_le_bytes(input)
}

#[proc_macro_derive(ToLeBytes)]
pub fn derive_to_le_bytes(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    to_le_bytes(input)
}
```

Since this is the first macro I ever wrote, I'd like to have feedback on how I could improve its implementation.